# How to use openid connect with flutter on spring security

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-security, dart, openid-connect

I created a spring boot service that is secured by the spring-security-keycloak-adapter. As the service already knows about the (keycloak) identity provider, I don't see any point in sending the issuerUrl and clientId to the mobile client to login directly into keycloak. Instead, I want to simply call the loginurl of the service in a webview on the client. In my understanding spring should redirect to keycloak and in the end return the token.
Unfortunately all flutter packages require the clientId and issuerUrl for the oauth process

I alread tried the [openid_client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) package for flutter

As your can see in the following code example from the official repository it requires the clientId and issuerUrl

```dart
// import the io version
import 'package:openid_client/openid_client_io.dart';

authenticate(Uri uri, String clientId, List<String> scopes) async {   

    // create the client
    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);

    // create an authenticator
    var authenticator = new Authenticator(client,
        scopes: scopes,
        port: 4000);

    // starts the authentication
    var c = await authenticator.authorize(); // this will open a browser

    // return the user info
    return await c.getUserInfo();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I ask because it sounds like you already have your answer to how to use flutter - flutter indeed requires the issuerUri and clientId to work.

Comment: But why does it need those two information. When I open a protected url in my browser, it already redirects me correctly to the identity provider.
So there is no other option as providing the client those information and he directly contacts the identity provider?

Comment: I've added an answer based on your clarification. I'd also recommend that you change your question in the title of your post so that it can help other Flutter users who have your same question.

Answer (score 0):

**Full disclosure:** I didn't write Flutter, but I did write some of the related client code for [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#startup-expectations).

*Why issuerUri?* The reason for this is likely for [OIDC Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#rfc.section.4.2). You can use the issuer to infer the other authorization server endpoints. This cuts down on configuration for you: You don't need to specify the token endpoint, the authorization endpoint, and on and on. If you supply only the issuer, then flutter figures out the rest.

Note that with Spring Security, this is just one configuration option among multiple, but something needs to be specified either way so the app knows where to go. I can't speak for flutter, but it may just be a matter of time before it supports more configuration modes.

*Why clientId?* This is a security measure and is required by [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1). If someone is calling my API, I want to know who it is. Additionally, authorization servers will use this `client_id` to do things like make sure that the `redirect_uri` in the `/authorize` request matches what is configured for that `client_id`.

Comment: So, as the identity provider should be configurable on the server component, there is no other way than basically sending all login related information (issuerUrl and clientId) to the client?

Comment: Not sure I understand that question. The client (the app that's asking for authorization) should have these two values as part of its initial configuration. Under what circumstances would those values be sent to the client? For example, the redirect_uri is something the client sends to the authorization server, not the other way around. Could be that I'm just misunderstanding what you are asking.